Media max-width is not the same on Mac
I'm setting a media max-width to change a margin-top property on mobile.
It works on my iphone and windows computer (chrome) but doesnt work on my Mac (chrome too). Maybe a problem of resolution but the margin-top is not the same when resizing the windows to mobile size on mac.
Here is my CSS :
.mobcont {
  margin-top:640px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* Appliquer une hauteur de 200px uniquement sur les appareils mobiles */
  .mobcont {
    margin-top: 355px !important;
  }
}


Thanks !
I tried to change the max-width value but nothing worked.
Added <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> to my file but nothing changes

Maybe you have zoom in your browser?

Use your browser inspector (on your Mac) to see which CSS rules are being applied and check the calculated value of margin-top.
